# Remove data-toggle attribute when disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I have a list of tabs with elements that can be disabled - i.e. non-clickable. And when 'disabled' is added as a class, then the mouse over on the element is indicating that the tab is non-clickable. Unfortunately the element is clickable.
I am trying to remove the `datatoggle="tab"` from the element when the element is disabled, but my jQuery skills aren't sufficient.

I have a ul of `class="nav nav-tabs" with id="myTabs"`
And I'm trying to remove the data-toggle attribute with this jQuery statement:

```
$('#myTabs a').is('.disabled').removeAttr('data-toggle');
```

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/uZpYdb9iQV)

Comment: You're looking for an `<a>` element that is disabled, but actually the class is applied to the `<li>` element.

Comment: Does the active/inactive state of the `li` elements change in your page, or do they remain 'static'?

Comment: Well active state changes when a tab is selected - are you thinking of disabled/enabled state?
The elements can change disabled/enabled state - and that is actually my next problem. It seems that UI does not change: If a tab changes from disabled to enabled, then the mouse over icon, still looks like the tab is disabled.
This is a new problem and I will properbly create a new question if I can't solve the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
$('#tabs li.disabled').find('a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
```

or

```
$('#tabs li.disabled a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/OhBwecMVo9)

Answer (score 1):

$('#myTabs a').is('.disabled') returns a boolean: false - you cannot call removeAttr on this!

Second your disabled class is on your li, not your .

Try this:

```
$('#myTabs li.disabled a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
```